# Create dynamic key and assign value in typescript variable

Tags: angular, typescript

In my component created the variable with the of any[], as per my requirement dynamic value will come from service based on that variable has to create and assign the value.

```
export class CostsComponent implements OnInit {

  public info: any[] = [];
  constructor(private deliverablesService: DeliverablesService, private setupcostsService: SetupcostsService, private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe((params: Params) => {
      this.setupcostsService.getcostDetails(2940).subscribe(
        data => {
          this.info.col = data.col; // dynamic
          this.info.data = data.data; //dynamic
          console.log('cost Info',data);
        },
        () => { }
      );

    });
  }
```

while setting `this.info.col` getting the `Property 'col' does not exist on type 'any[]'`. error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> You are initialize the variable as an `array`, you can't read an `array` property without using `index`. So you should define that variable as an `object` instead of `array`.

Try `public info: any = {};` instead of `public info: any[] = [];`

I hope this below discussion may help you.

[What is the difference between any and any[ ]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44069326/what-is-the-difference-between-any-and-any)